# Unable to login to the sitecore.demo.edge site after installing

Tags: docker, identity-server, login, nextjs

https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Demo.Edge This is a docker demo site from Sitecore using JSS and Next.js

Unable to log in to the `sitecore.demo.edge` site after installing, the value in the `.env` file for the admin password is `b`, and tried resetting in the SQL core DB. It redirects identity and keeps saying invalid username and password. I also tried `sitecore\admin` as well. Are there any issues with this demo site? No errors in the identity logs or cm logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are setting up [Sitecore Demo Edge](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Demo.Edge) website on your local, to login to Sitecore CMS use the below credentials:

```
User name: superuser
Password: the password you set in the .env file (eg. 'b')
```

If you are spinning up, the Demo Edge website on Sitecore Demo Portal, you will get the user name and password in the details section:

[image]

Comment: Thank you and there was no mention to figure out that the username has changed from admin to the superuser, the issue was the username, I was trying with admin.